# Pandas - get a summarized pivot DataFrame from row counts

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given this DataFrame:

```
    bowl    cookie
0   one     chocolate
1   two     chocolate
2   two     chocolate
3   two     vanilla
4   one     vanilla
5   one     vanilla
6   one     vanilla
7   one     vanilla
8   one     vanilla
9   two     chocolate
```

I'd like to obtain the following summarized DataFrame:

```
        vanilla     chocolate
one     5           1
two     1           3
```

Apart from proceeding manually with:

```
vanilla_bowl1 = len(df_picks[(df_picks['bowl'] == 'one') & (df_picks['cookie'] == 'vanilla')])
vanilla_bowl2 = len(df_picks[(df_picks['bowl'] == 'two') & (df_picks['cookie'] == 'vanilla')])
chocolate_bowl1 = ...
chocolate_bowl2 = ...
```

Is there a way to do that in a single operation with `Pandas`?

---

**Note**: I've had a look at `df.pivot()` and this would work provided that I add a column `count` equal to `1` in each row:

```
    bowl    cookie      count
0   one     chocolate       1
1   two     chocolate       1
2   two     chocolate       1
3   two     vanilla         1
4   one     vanilla         1
5   one     vanilla         1
6   one     vanilla         1
7   one     vanilla         1
8   one     vanilla         1
9   two     chocolate       1
```

And then

```
df.pivot(index='bowl', columns='cookie', values='count')
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a more direct method, that wouldn't require adding the `count` column in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most concise way is probably the `pandas.crosstab` function:

```
>>> pandas.crosstab(d.bowl, d.cookie)
cookie  chocolate  vanilla
bowl                      
one             1        5
two             3        1
```

Comment: That's true, but it's bit slower compared to pivot_table and `groupby([...]).aggfunc().unstack` solutions

Answer (score 2):

you can use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method:

```
In [33]: df.pivot_table(index='bowl', columns='cookie', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
Out[33]:
cookie  chocolate  vanilla
bowl
one             1        5
two             3        1
```

alternatively you can use `groupby()`, `size()` and `unstack()` - that's how `pivot_table()` does it under the hood:

```
In [36]: df.groupby(['bowl', 'cookie']).size().unstack('cookie', fill_value=0)
Out[36]:
cookie  chocolate  vanilla
bowl
one             1        5
two             3        1
```

Timing for 100K rows DF:

```
In [48]: big = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [49]: big.shape
Out[49]: (100000, 2)

In [50]: %timeit pd.crosstab(big.bowl, big.cookie)
10 loops, best of 3: 58 ms per loop

In [51]: %timeit big.pivot_table(index='bowl', columns='cookie', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 38.4 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit big.groupby(['bowl', 'cookie']).size().unstack('cookie', fill_value=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.2 ms per loop

In [118]: %timeit pir(big)
1 loop, best of 3: 631 ms per loop

In [119]: big.shape
Out[119]: (100000, 2)
```

Timing for 1M rows DF:

```
In [53]: big = pd.concat([big] * 10, ignore_index=True)

In [54]: big.shape
Out[54]: (1000000, 2)

In [55]: %timeit pd.crosstab(big.bowl, big.cookie)
1 loop, best of 3: 446 ms per loop

In [56]: %timeit big.pivot_table(index='bowl', columns='cookie', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 333 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit big.groupby(['bowl', 'cookie']).size().unstack('cookie', fill_value=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 327 ms per loop

In [121]: %timeit pir(big)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.08 s per loop

In [122]: big.shape
Out[122]: (1000000, 2)
```

Comment: can you add my method to your timing?  Thanks

Comment: @piRSquared, added timing for `pir()` function

Comment: Wow!  I missed the mark on that. I must find another way. Thx

Answer (score 1):

a numpy approach

```
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def pir(df):
    ub = pd.Index(np.unique(df.values[:, 0]), name='bowl')
    uc = pd.Index(np.unique(df.values[:, 1]), name='cookie')
    u = np.array(list(product(ub.values, uc.values)))
    e = u[:, None] == df.values

    return pd.DataFrame(
        e.all(2).sum(1).reshape(-1, 2),
        ub, uc
    )

pir(df)
```

[image]